# What is for square brackets in scala when we use them before declaration of trait or object

Tags: scala

I have seen below code in Scala Redis client.
What does `[redis]` will do?

```
package object redis {
  private[redis] trait Reply
  private[redis] trait R extends Reply
  private[redis] object Commands
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`private[redis]` means that the trait or object is only usable by code inside the `redis` package. Code in other packages cannot access the value.

Comment: Important to mention that it is visible to *any* sub-package inside the `redis` package, unlike Java.

Answer (score 1):

that means a method/class/object/trait is only visible to other classes in the same package.

Is one of the existing scala access levels:

- Public
- Package private
- Package
- Private

See more details at https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package